# Render different columns in Primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, radio-button, javabeans

I have a datatable on a page with columns Unit/Set, Vehicle, Next Maintenance, Day 1,...,Day 7. I have two radio buttons also to change the sorting of the data, when I change to the other radio button which sorts by Date instead of Unit/Set the columns should change to Date, A Exams, B Exams, C Exams,...

I assume I need to create two datatables and then use the rendered attribute to decide which table is shown depending on which sort is selected.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTableEnquiryNextDue" styleClass="editable-datatable"
                rows="20"
                scrollable="true"
                frozenColumns="2"
                rendered=>                                          
                <p:column headerText="Unit/Set" />
                <p:column headerText="Vehicle" />
                <p:column headerText="Next Maintenance" />
                <p:column headerText="Day 1" />
                <p:column headerText="Day 2" />
                <p:column headerText="Day 3" />
                <p:column headerText="Day 4" />
                <p:column headerText="Day 5" />
                <p:column headerText="Day 6" />
                <p:column headerText="Day 7" />|
            </p:dataTable>
```

This is my code for the datatable, except I have left the rendered blank at the minute, I believe I'll have to make some kind of bean, I think it will get the value of the radio buttons then I will have something like

```
rendered="#{Bean.searchSort == Unit}
```

or

```
rendered="#{Bean.searchSort == Date}
```

I have created a bean with the following code

```
@ManagedBean
```

@ViewScoped
public class DepotWorkloadBean implements Serializable {

```
public enum Sort    {
    UNIT, DATE
}

private Sort sortMode = Sort.UNIT;

public Sort getSortMode() {
    return sortMode;
}

public void enterUnitSort() {
    sortMode = Sort.UNIT;       
}

public void enterDateSort() {
    sortMode = Sort.DATE;
}
```

}

And in my table added the line

```
rendered="#{depotWorkloadBean.sortMode == 'UNIT'}"
```

I have also created my other table the same way but with

```
rendered="#{depotWorkloadBean.sortMode == 'DATE'}"
```

and different columns.

For my radio buttons I have written

```
            <p:radioButton id="UnitSetNumber" for="customRadio3" itemIndex="0"  
        onchange="#{depotWorkloadBean.enterUnitSort}" update="dataTableDaySortUnit dataTableDaySortDate"/>

            <p:radioButton id="DateDue" for="customRadio3" itemIndex="1"
        onchange="#{depotWorkloadBean.enterDateSort}" update="dataTableDaySortUnit dataTableDaySortDate"/>
```

At the moment I am getting an error saying

The class 'DepotWorkloadBean' does not have the property 'enterUnitSort'.

This is quite confusing as it clearly does and as far as I can tell I have spelt everything correctly. I'm still not sure if my approach is actually correct though, so again any advice will be appreciated.

Here is my selectOneRadio

```
                <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio3" layout="custom">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="UnitSetNumber" itemValue="1" binding="{depotWorkloadBean.enterUnitSort}"
                update=":mainForm"/>
                <!-- <f:ajax listener="#{depotWorkloadBean.enterUnitSort}" render="@all"/> -->
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="DateDue" itemValue="2" binding="{depotWorkloadBean.enterDateSort}"
                update=":mainForm"/>
                <!-- <f:ajax listener="#{depotWorkloadBean.enterDateSort}" render="@all"/> -->
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="DueInValue" itemValue="3" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
```

EDIT: Here is my updated selectOneRadio

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio3" layout="custom"
            value="#{depotWorkloadBean.sortMode}"
            update=":mainForm">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="UNIT.name" itemValue="UNIT" value="#{depotWorkloadBean.sortMode}"
                var="UNIT"/>
                <!-- <f:ajax listener="#{depotWorkloadBean.enterUnitSort}" render="@all"/> -->
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="DATE.name" itemValue="DATE" value="#{depotWorkloadBean.sortMode}"
                var="DATE"/>
                <!-- <f:ajax listener="#{depotWorkloadBean.enterDateSort}" render="@all"/> -->
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="DueInValue" itemValue="3" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
```

And here is my updated bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DepotWorkloadBean implements Serializable {



   public enum Sort {
        UNIT, DATE
    }

    private Sort sortMode = Sort.UNIT;

    public Sort getSortMode() {
        return sortMode;
    }

    public Sort[] getSortValues() {
        return Sort.values();
    }

    public void setSortMode(Sort sortMode) {
        this.sortMode = sortMode;
    }
}
```

EDIT: After a bit of thinking I have taken a new approach, so now my radio button group is like so:

```
    <!-- <f:facet name="actions"> -->
        <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio3" layout="custom"
        partialSubmit="true"
        value="#{depotWorkloadBean.selectSort}">
            <p:ajax update="mainForm" listener="#{depotWorkloadBean.updateSortMode}"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="UnitSet" itemValue="UnitSet"/>        
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="DateDue" itemValue="DateDue"/>            
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="DueInValue" itemValue="DueInValue"/>                     
        </p:selectOneRadio>
    <!-- </f:facet> -->
```

I have commented out the facet tag as it causes the error 
`"javax.servlet.ServletException"` and I have no idea why.

My tables are as they were before except the rendered line is now

```
rendered="#{depotWorkloadBean.sortMode == 'UnitSet'}">
```

and similar for 'DateDue'. And my bean is as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DepotWorkloadBean implements Serializable {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DepotWorkloadBean.class);

/*public enum Sort {
    UNIT, DATE
}

private Sort sortMode = Sort.UNIT;*/

private String sortMode = "UnitSet";
private String selectSort = "UnitSet";

public void updateSortMode () {
    log.info("In updateSortMode " + " State [" + selectSort + "]");
    sortMode = selectSort;
}

public String getSortMode() {
    return sortMode;
}

public void setSortMode(String sortMode) {
    this.sortMode = sortMode;
}

public String getSelectSort() {
    return selectSort;
}

public void setSelectSort(String selectSort) {
    log.info("Setting selectSort to [" + selectSort + "]");
    this.selectSort = selectSort;
    sortMode = selectSort;
}
```

I have only just found out about the log and it seems very useful. When my page builds and I click between the radio buttons my log records 'In updateSortMode State []' "Setting selectSort to State []" so there is clearly something going wrong in the method. The other thing I should mention is my radio buttons are actually displayed further down in the same panelGrid, like so..

```
        <p:row>
    <p:column>
        <p:radioButton id="UnitSetNumber" for="customRadio3" itemIndex="0"/>
    </p:column>    
    <p:column>
        <h:outputLabel for="UnitSetNumber" value="Unit/set number" />
    </p:column>        
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
    <p:column>
        <p:radioButton id="DateDue" for="customRadio3" itemIndex="1"/>
    </p:column>    
    <p:column>
        <h:outputLabel for="DateDue" value="Date due" />
    </p:column>        
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
    <p:column>
        <p:radioButton id="DueInValue" for="customRadio3" itemIndex="2" />
    </p:column>    
    <p:column>
        <h:outputLabel for="DueInValue" value="Due in value" />
    </p:column>        
    </p:row>
```

Not sure if that would affect the ajax listener?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `onchange` listener, the `update=` attribute will do the job.

Use a `<p:selectOneRadio>` with a nested `<f:selectitems>` that will set the `sortMode` value of your bean  (you might need a converter). Then ensure the parent component of both tables is updated upon selection. This will re-evaluate the `rendered=` attributes of your tables with the newly set `sortMode` valule.

Example:
The view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:selectOneRadio id="radiogroup"
                              value="#{testController.selectedValue}">
                <f:ajax render=":content"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{testController.valuesTypes}"
                               var="val"
                               itemLabel="#{val.name()}"
                               itemValue="#{val}"/>
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="content">
            <p:outputPanel rendered="#{testController.selectedValue eq 'VALUEA'}">
                Value A panel
            </p:outputPanel>
            <p:outputPanel rendered="#{testController.selectedValue eq 'VALUEB'}">
                Value B panel
            </p:outputPanel>
            <p:outputPanel rendered="#{testController.selectedValue eq 'VALUEC'}">
                Value C panel
            </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And the bean:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestController {

    public enum ValueTypes {

        VALUEA,
        VALUEB,
        VALUEC
    }

    private ValueTypes selectedValue;

    public ValueTypes getSelectedValue() {
        return selectedValue;
    }

    public void setSelectedValue(ValueTypes selectedValue) {
        this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        selectedValue = ValueTypes.VALUEA;
    }

    public ValueTypes[] getValuesTypes() {
        return ValueTypes.values();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added my selectOneRadio to my question, which I have just tried to add a binding too. Also you can see my attempted ajax code which I had tried earlier, but had problems with also. Not sure binding is the right thing to use, but not sure what else I can use?

Comment: I have written '<f:selectItem itemLabel="sortUnit.name" itemValue="sortUnit" value="{depotWorkloadBean.enterUnitSort}"
             var="sortUnit"/>' and similarly for the other radio button. Also I have '<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio3" layout="custom"
   value="#{depotWorkloadBean.getSortMode}"
   update=":mainForm">' and have added what you suggested to my bean, but aren't sure if they're meant to be replacing what I already have or in addition to, in which case where do I refer to them?

Comment: You don't your enter*() functions. The member variable sortMode, provided your bean has proper getter and setter, will be updated automatically if the value= attribute of the p:selectOneRadio point to it (you can use "#{depotWorkloadBean.sortMode}")

Comment: I have tried a few different things and am getting "DepotWorkloadBean$Sort cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem" I'll post my updated code in my question...

Comment: You need to implements a converter for the Sort.class. See http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/. Otherwise, you could maybe try using the name of the Sort object as the item value. You should then add a sortName property with proper getter/setter in your bean.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. I've tried reading about the converter class, but am struggling to follow exactly how it works and can't see how I could use it in my case. As for using the name of the Sort object as item value do you mean calling itemValue="DATE" or "UNIT" as I have above? Then I'd create a string called sortName with getter/setter which get and set sortMode? If that makes any sense..

Comment: when you set the attribute itemValue=#{someExpr}, you need to tell JSF how to handle this value. So either you use the name of your ENUM value (<p:selectOne... value=#{bean.sortModeName}> and <f:select... itemValue=#{bean.sortMode.name()}>), along with String sortModeName in your bean. I think using strings would work. Otherwise, you have to specify how to convert values of class 'Sort' to/from strings by implenting a FacesConverter.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I turned my mind to other things the reapproached the problem, I have posted my new approach above and I think it should cut out the ENUM to string problem, but still am having issues, wondering if you have and advice for these issues? Thanks

Comment: The <f:selectItem> value (in your case, for the first one, that will be "UnitSet") will be bound to the <p:selectOneRadio> value (in your case, that is #{depotWorkloadBean.sortMode}"). So there is no reason the selectSort variable is touched at all (thats what your print in your log). I've never used the p:radiobutton tags however, maybe you need to add an update= attribute to each of them.

Comment: It should be #{depotWorkloadBean.selectSort}", I've changed that and now the log gives 'Setting selectSort to []' and 'In updateSortMode State to []' so it seems to be running through the process as I want it to but not getting the names UnitSet or Date from anywhere, I thought it would read them from itemValue. I'll try adding updates to the radiobuttons though

Comment: I've added update=":customRadio3" and update="content" (the name of the whole ui:define everything is in) and it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: I edited my answer with a full tested working example